# When does SQL SEQUENCE CACHE reset

Tags: sql, caching, sql-server-2012, sequence

Here's the SQL sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[ColumnID] 
AS [bigint]
START WITH 1000
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE -9223372036854775808
MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
CACHE 
GO
```

This is used to auto generate the column ID (not sure if it's good practice).
That CASHE keyword is used to cache the value in memory correct?
IF SQL server is restarted will this value reset and start again from 1000?
If it does reset then there will be duplicate column ID's right?

Just want to make sure I understand what this sequence is doing.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on what does the keyword `cache` is doing

Comment: I think this is the answer to my question. Thanks